# Java program could not load image file

Tags: java, image, for-loop, file-upload, pixel

I am trying to run a program to manipulate the individual pixel colors of a digital image to produce a variety of special effects, but the picture file is not loading. I saved the picture as WashingtonMonument.jpg and everytime I run it, it results in a black screen that says it could not be loaded.

My program is:

```
import java.awt.*
public class TrueColorsDemo
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Picture pictureObj = new Picture("WashingtonMonument.jpg");
        pictureObj.explore();
        int redValue = 0; int greenValue = 0; int blueValue = 0;

        Pixel targetPixel = new Pixel(pictureObj, 0,0);
        Color pixelColor = null;

        for(int y=0; y < pictureObj.getHeight(); y++)
        {
            for(int x = 0; x < pictureObj.getWidth(); x++)
            {
                 targetPixel = pictureObj.getPixel(x,y);
                 pixelColor = targetPixel.getColor();

                 redValue = pixelColor.getRed();
                 greenValue = pixelColor.getGreen();
                 blueValue = pixelColor.getBlue();

                 pixelColor = new Color(redValue, greenValue, blueValue);
                 targetPixel.setColor(pixelColor);
             }
        }

        pictureObj.explore();
        pictureObj.write("NewWashingtonMonument.jpg");
        pictureObj.show();
    }
}
```

If someone could help me figure out how to load the picture to get it to work on my program that would be great! Thanks

Comment: Show us the `Picture` class?

Comment: Im sorry but what do you mean by that? @Gosu

Comment: is `Picture` some built-in Java class, or a class that you wrote?

Comment: Just a wild guess: Have you tried to use an absolute path to load your image? E.g. `Picture pictureObj = new Picture("/path/to/WashingtonMonument.jpg")`.

Comment: What is the import statement for `Picture`?

Comment: This program was given to me to test. I did not write it my teacher did   @Gosu

Comment: isn't it import.java.awt.* @Pasupathi

Comment: Don't think `Picture` is part of java.awt?

Comment: `Picture` cannot be resolved to a type for me. Without that we cannot help you. Else there should be a class named Picture.java in the same package where TrueColorsDemo exist. If possible post the Picture.java code. Else we can achieve this using `BufferedImage`

Comment: Is the programing compiling for you... without proper import for Picture class... I did not find Picture class in java.awt package...

Comment: @PavanKumarK Because it is indeed not part of `java.awt`, most likely given by his teacher.